# Imprimir imagem (relative path) Jasper Report

Tags: jasper-reports, jasper

Bom dia a todos!
Estou tentando imprimir uma logo no relatorio do Jasper Reports
se eu colocar o endereço "http://meuservidor.com.br/imagens/logo.png" funciona,

mas eu queria colocar o caminho da imagem que está dentro da minha aplicação
(ex: "../imagens/logo.png")

segue abaixo estrutura

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Vou reverter a edição, não é um fórum em que indicamos que foi solucionado no título, mas sim em marcar uma resposta como aceita

Answer (score 1):

Bom dia pessoal!
Consegui resolver fazendo o seguinte:

criei um parametro no relatorio chamado LOGO_DIR
que corresponde a pasta de imagens do meu sistema

e preenchi na chamada do relatorio

ClasseRelatorio.java ...

```
FacesContext fc = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
ServletContext context = (ServletContext)fc.getExternalContext().getContext();
String path = context.getRealPath(File.separator) + "resources/jasper" + File.separator;
String logo = context.getRealPath(File.separator) + "resources/images" + File.separator;
params.put("SUBREPORT_DIR", path);
params.put("LOGO_DIR", logo);
```

dentro do relatorio, no jasper, criei um campo String que recebe o parametro LOGO_DIR + "nomeDaImagem.png"

Answer (score 0):

Olá amigo eu faço da seguinte forma para Aplicações desktop em Jar

```
getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("br/com/blogspot/denisbenjamim/iReport/Imagens/logotp.png")
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]